# BigQuery SQL: Cannot query the cross product of repeated fields /

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

My goal is to filter from all visitors, to only analyse customers (which are in the `customDimension.index =2` and then further filter only specific types of pageviews for the customers.

```
SELECT customDimensions.value AS CustomerID,
SUM(totals.pageviews) as page_views,
SUM(CASE WHEN hits.type = 'PAGE' AND hits.contentGroup.contentGroup2 = 'important' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS important_pageviews
FROM `xxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_20180415`
WHERE customDimensions.index = 2
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

I get the error that (using StandardSQL):

```
Error: Cannot access field index on a value with type
ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>> at [5:24]
```

For Legacy SQL:

> Error: Cannot query the cross product of repeated fields
>   customDimensions.index and hits.contentGroup.contentGroup2.

**Edit:**

```
SELECT cd.value AS CustomerID,
SUM(totals.pageviews) as page_views,
SUM(CASE WHEN hits.type = 'PAGE' AND hits.contentGroup.contentGroup2 = 'important' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS important_pageviews
FROM `xxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_20180415`,
UNNEST(customDimensions) AS cd
WHERE cd.index = 2
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

returns:

```
Error: Cannot access field type on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, time INT64, hour INT64, ...>> at [3:20]
```

I tried correcting the line 3:20 using `UNNEST(hits.type) = 'PAGE' AND UNNEST(hitscontentGroup.contentGroup2) = 'important'` which gives 
`Error: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword UNNEST at [3:15]`

Comment: I guess you are looking for [unnest](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest). `FROM xxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_20180415, unnset(customDimensions) as cd where cd.index = 2` (also you can unnest in an Subquery to preserver number of rows )

Comment: @danihp I still get the same error (standard SQL) - Error: Cannot access field value on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING>> at [1:25]

Comment: @GRS . . . You have an *array*.  You need to extract one or more elements from the array for the query.  It would help if we could see what the data looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As customDimensions is an array you'll need to `unnest` this in order to refer to it's contents, see the StandardSQL example below where I unnest UserIDs from Google Analytics data in BigQuery:

```
SELECT customDimension.value AS UserID
FROM `my.project.data` AS t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
  WHERE customDimension.index = 2
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm trying to combine 2 unnests together. After adding on the second line `t.hits.contentGroup.contentGroup2`, to get data about the number of pages viewed by these customers, I return to my error.

Comment: Sorry, where is your second unnest, I can only see one? You can add another unnest directly after the first to unnest further?